# BIOS doesn't recognize ext3 drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, linux-mint, ext

I made a bootable usb with linux mint **installed** onto it, I tried formatting it as ext3 and ext4 but no luck, on my laptop's bios at least. It works on my main rig, but not my laptop, yet to try any other pcs

Comment: BIOS knows nothing about filesystems at all. It operates with physical sectors only.

Comment: You need to tell bios which device you want to boot from, that's all.

Comment: Im not really sure what is wrong since when I put windows (ntfs) on it works fine.